# About usability issues for Eclipse's auto completion

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, usability

Recently, I need to use Eclipse instead of Netbeans.

I find the following issues is annoying in my case. Say, I key in the following wrong method name.

[image]

So, I tend to fix the error, by deleting the wrong method name (But not parameter, as I know I want to pass in `true`), including the dot. I key in dot again, Eclipse auto completion will prompts me list of methods

[image]

I am happy with the suggestion. I press ENTER. However, this is what I am getting.

[image]

Now, I need to manually deleted the uselesss **(checked)**. This is pretty annoying, especially when the method takes in 4 to 5 parameters. I have to delete them 1 by 1.

I consider this a usability defect. I do not have such issue in Netbeans. Anyone of you know any workaround to overcome this usability issues? Is there any options I can turn on or turn off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also press Ctrl+Enter to insert the completion which will 'replace' the incorrect typed word.

Look for "Toggle between inserting and replacing content assist" in http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Java > Editor > Content Assist preference page solves.